# I want to do animation like album and artist animation in native music app iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to do animation like album and artist in native music app

Comment: At least try to do it before asking the question.

Comment: 1) The question you've asked isn't clear at all. What are you looking for specifically? Include at least a screenshot or video of what you're trying to accomplish.

2) What have you tried? Have you tried at all? We're here to help but you need to put forth some effort.

Comment: I did it.. thank you guys. Below you can find the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it myself and here is the code

```
- (void)animateWithCurrentView:(UIView *)currentView {
    NSLog(@"center poin is %f %f",animationPoint.x,animationPoint.y);
//songsView.hidden = NO;
//[self.view bringSubviewToFront:songsView];

//flip the view by 180 degrees in its place first.
currentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(currentView.layer.transform,myRotationAngle(180), 0, 1, 0);

//set the anchor point so that the view rotates on one of its sides.
currentView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
/**
 * Set up scaling
 */
CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kResizeKey];

//we are going to fill the screen here. So 423,337
[resizeAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(423, 337)]];
resizeAnimation.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards;
resizeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;


/**
 * Set up path movement
 */
UIBezierPath *movePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    //the control point is now set to centre of the filled screen. Change this to make the path different.
    // CGPoint ctlPoint       = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
CGPoint ctlPoint       = CGPointMake(1024/2, 768/2);

//This is the starting point of the animation. This should ideally be a function of the frame of the view to be animated. Hardcoded here.

// Set here to get the accurate point..
[movePath moveToPoint:animationPoint];

//The anchor point is going to end up here at the end of the animation.
[movePath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(1024/2, 768/2) controlPoint:ctlPoint];

CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kPathMovement];

moveAnim.path                = movePath.CGPath;
moveAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

/**
 * Setup rotation animation
 */
CABasicAnimation* rotateAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kRotation];
//start from 180 degrees (done in 1st line)
CATransform3D fromTransform       = CATransform3DMakeRotation(myRotationAngle(180), 0, 1, 0);
//come back to 0 degrees
CATransform3D toTransform         = CATransform3DMakeRotation(myRotationAngle(0), 0, 1, 0);

//This is done to get some perspective.
CATransform3D persp1 = CATransform3DIdentity;
persp1.m34 = 1.0 / -3000;

fromTransform = CATransform3DConcat(fromTransform, persp1);
toTransform = CATransform3DConcat(toTransform,persp1);

rotateAnimation.toValue             = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:toTransform];
rotateAnimation.fromValue           = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:fromTransform];
//rotateAnimation.duration            = 2;
rotateAnimation.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards;
rotateAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

/**
 * Setup and add all animations to the group
 */
CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation]; 

[group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnim,rotateAnimation, resizeAnimation, nil]];

group.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards;
group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
group.duration            = 0.7f;
group.delegate            = self;

[group setValue:currentView forKey:kGroupAnimation];

/**
 * ...and go
 */
[currentView.layer addAnimation:group forKey:kLayerAnimation]; 
}
```